# Dealing with Multiple Flag Cases

Tags: java, c++, performance, flags

I'm wondering how to best deal with multiple flag cases, for example I have 5 flags that I need to check: `t d y r g` and I need to check all cases of such flags. What is a better way of doing so instead of,

```
if(t && d && y && r && g) {}
else if(t && d && y && r) {}
else if(t && d && y && g) {}
....
else if(t) {}
else if(d) {}
```

Comment: Why do you need to check for certain combinations of flags in the first place? Isn't it enough to handle them individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the flags to single bits and perform binary operations on them.

Assume there are five flags: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e`.
Valid values for all flags are `0x1` and `0x0`.

1. Convert to `uint8_t`:

   ```
   uint8_t flags;
   flags |= a;
   flags |= b << 0x1;
   flags |= c << 0x2;
   flags |= d << 0x3;
   flags |= e << 0x4;
   flags |= f << 0x5;
   ```

   If you stored all flags in an array from the beginning and denoted them via macros as indices like this:

   ```
   #define IGNORE_CASE 0x0
   ...

   bool flag_array[NUM_FLAGS];

   flag_array[IGNORE_CASE] = SOME_VALUE;
   ```

   the whole conversion process could be simplified to a loop.
2. Now you can conveniently compare with specific bit masks.

   To check if `a` and `b` are set, use

   ```
   if (flags & (0x1 + 0x2))
   ```

   To check if `b` and `f` are set, use

   ```
   if (flags & (0x2 + 0x20))
   ```

   The cleaner way would be to define macros or constants for the flag bit masks and use these macros, not the plain hexadecimal bit masks.